# Is there a way to pass in parameters to a MySQL stored procedure in any order?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here's the start of my typical stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`joe`@`%` PROCEDURE `Add_Item`(
  IN usernameApp VARCHAR(255),
  IN barcodeApp VARCHAR(255),
  IN quantityApp VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
```

I would call it with something like this code from PHP:

```
CALL Add_Item('ethan', '987261826671', '12');
```

The issue is that I am looking for something a bit more dynamic, where I can call the stored procedure with parameters in any order (because I can't guarantee the order in my dynamic app I'm trying to create). I feel like named parameters would work, but I know MySQL doesn't have that for procedures.

Something like this would work, for example (pseudo code obviously):

```
CALL Add_Item(quantity>'12' name>'ethan', barcode>'987261826671');
```

Ideas?

Comment: no. there is no way to do `add_item(quantityapp = 12, usernameapp='ethan',etc...)`. you pass the parameters in the other they're defined in the sproc, or you don't pass anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL Add_Item(:quantity, :name, :barcode)');
// You can pass paremeters in any order here:
$sth->execute([
    ':quantity' => 12,
    ':name' => 'ethan',
    ':barcode' => '987261826671',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to a stored proc are fixed. There are no optional arguments and the order is fixed. There's no such thing as named arguments like in Perl or Python.

A workaround you could do is the following:

```
SET @quantity = 12;
SET @name = 'ethan';
SET @barcode = '987261826671';
CALL Add_Item();
```

In other words, use session variables instead of procedure arguments. Then you can set the session variables in any order you want.

Session variables can be referenced within procedure code simply by using the `@` prefix. Session variables are visible only within the current session.

But this workaround doesn't work well for recursive procedures, where you want to pass parameters to the procedure in recursive calls.

Also, if you call the procedure multiple times during your session, you'd have to remember to change the values or else the values from prior calls could carry over to subsequent calls.

I have to say this is an odd question. Many programming languages, even PHP, require you to call a function or procedure with arguments in a specific order. This isn't too difficult a constraint.